# Task manager menu, titlebar and tabs have disappeared

Tags: windows, task-manager

I was reading a question tonight about our dear friend, the Windows Task Manager and remembered, just then, one particular area of confuzzlement about it that it took me a long time to clear up the first time and it was only by dumb luck I found the solution.

Have you ever discovered your Task Manager in this condition?

[image]

Restarting it doesn't help, there are no obvious ways of getting the menu, tabs and taskbar to come back again. So how is this solved exactly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you double-click the clear border between the task area and the resizing borders, the task manager expands back to it's regular settings.

This is, without a doubt, one of the weirdest features I have ever come across in Windows.

Hope this helps someone from having to finally solve this by randomly clicking everywhere on the window.

Answer (score 1):

This is called Tiny footprint mode and it's useful to keep it always on top with the borders disabled for Administrators with multiple monitors, so they can see more processes and information at once. Albeit I was confused at first too, but it gets handy in the server administration field.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice feature for the "Performance" or "Networking" tab, where you can have the moving graph take up most of the window space. Resizing it to a smaller size and setting the "Always on top" option can provide a reasonably unobtrusive system monitor window.

Comment: That part of the feature I have no problem with, it's the extremely unintuitive activation that gets me.

Comment: Also, I see no reason why the behaviour should persist the next time you start it, especially when you consider someone activating this and then another person sitting down at the computer and using the task manager... I was mighty confused the first time.

Answer (score 0):

If you double-click the clear border between the task area and the resizing borders, the task manager expands back to it's regular settings. this is an ultimate and final thing to do..

Comment: This has already been answered.