# Why does my Task Manager window outline keep disappearing?

Tags: windows-vista, task-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Task manager menu, titlebar and tabs have disappeared](https://superuser.com/questions/9638/task-manager-menu-titlebar-and-tabs-have-disappeared)

I'm not sure what the proper term for the window outline is (chrome, I think?), but it keeps disappearing.

[image: I want my X back]

As you can see, theres no File->Exit or buttons that allow me to minimize or close this dialog. So instead it stays on top of everything else (unless I 'Switch To' another window). There is also no Processes tab or anything.

Since you cant right click the toolbar or bring up another instance of Task Manager, the only way to actually kill this dialog seems to be restarting. However the next time I bring up Task Manager, it will still refuse to go away.

Anyone know whats going on? I'm running 32-bit Vista SP1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a feature in Task Manager. Double click anywhere in the window and they will come back. It's sort of a mini mode that's been available for many years.

Comment: "It's not a bug, it's a feature!"

Answer (score 1):

It's called **tiny footprint mode**. Double click an area of the window to go back to normal.