# Task Manager not Displaying Correctly

Tags: windows, windows-xp, task-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Task manager menu, titlebar and tabs have disappeared](https://superuser.com/questions/9638/task-manager-menu-titlebar-and-tabs-have-disappeared)

When I launch the task manager for windows it displays but incorrectly, below is a screenshot of how it looks:

[image: Task Manager Display]

It normally has tabs above it with ways to close the task manager, only way I know how to close the task manager is by right clicking the task manager icon in the task bar - Screenshot:

[image: Task Bar Screenshot]

How do I fix this error?

I am running Windows XP (Service Pack 3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in Tiny Footprint mode. Try double-clicking the empty space around the list, that should restore the title bar, tabs and menus.

For more information:

- [Task Manager Menu Bar and Tabs Are Not Visible](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/task-manager-menu-bar-and-tabs-are-not-visible-8fa93165-7d0c-643f-62c4-61fe46c632fe)
- [Where did my Task Manager tabs and buttons go? - The Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040330-00/?p=39963)

Comment: Thanks, it would be much better if they had a button or something indicating that.