# Menu Tab not coming in Windows Task Manager

Tags: windows, task-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Task manager menu, titlebar and tabs have disappeared](https://superuser.com/questions/9638/task-manager-menu-titlebar-and-tabs-have-disappeared)

I am facing a problem with my Windows 7. I am not getting options that are shown above like the menu tab in my task manager. Currently it looks like this:
[image]

Can somebody tell me how to rectify it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/q/424101 and http://superuser.com/q/9638.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click the white area outside of any interface elements.

Comment: wow! it is solved. Does this happen only in task manager or other applications too?