# Task manager missing frames?

Tags: windows-7, task-manager, dll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Task manager menu, titlebar and tabs have disappeared](https://superuser.com/questions/9638/task-manager-menu-titlebar-and-tabs-have-disappeared)

When I hit Ctl-Alt-Del I get a "portion" of the task manager: it brings up the process screen, with no other tabs and not even the red X for exiting (in order to exit the task manager I need to kill the tskman process) I have tried system restore and even going into SFC/scannow but neither helps. Can you give me a suggestion/idea? I really did not want to have to reinstall it Windows!

Thanks.

Ross

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double Click on the "White area" just inside the border of the TaskManager window and you'll get back to Normal Task mode..

Comment: Yup!!  That did it!

Answer (score 2):

What version of windows are you running?  It is possible you are in the samll footprint task manager.  Double click the border just above the "image name" "User name" etc. columns.  You should then see all your tabs